# Apple approve multiple storyboard instead of Size class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uistoryboard

I have a project with complex design, so i prefer to use different storyboard according to size of the iPhone device, will apple approve it ?

Is any restriction to force to use auto layout?

How can i use minimum storyboard to achieve this task without using auto layout and size class?

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    // NSLog(@"Screen Height is %i", screenHeight);

    // grab correct storyboard depending on screen height
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self grabStoryboard];

    // display storyboard
    self.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {
    // determine screen size
    int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

    switch (screenHeight) {
            // iPhone 4s
        case 480:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-4s" bundle:nil];
            break;

            // iPhone 5s
        case 568:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-5s" bundle:nil];
            break;

            // iPhone 6
        case 667:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6" bundle:nil];
            break;

            // iPhone 6 Plus
        case 736:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6-Plus" bundle:nil];
            break;

        default:
            // it's an iPad
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            break;
    }
    return storyboard;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer

### Yes

Yes, Apple will approve the app.

However I would suggest using 1 storyboard instead of multiple storyboards.

Cons of using multiple storyboards are

- It take 200% more time than actual time. Think tomorrow when you will have more iPhones.
- It makes app size more bigger
- Worst part is it take more time for compile while working on the project & take more time when switching storyboards.

***The most bad thing is it have more chances of missing some changes in some storyboard.***

Answer (score 1):

YES! Apple will accept your app.

To help you factorize your design, you can use **storyboard references** to reuse storyboard parts common to every device.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-staying-organized-with-storyboard-references--cms-24226

(Only available from iOS 9)

Answer (score 0):

yes definitely apple will approve it, I have used it in one of my apps. But it may increase the memory consumption.